# Should BD in this sector means Brown dwarfs or Black dwarfs?

Tags: dwarf-star

The one in the sector as BD/NS/BH. And please explain why Brown/Black dwarf should be here among neutron stars and black holes. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Source: Beech, M. (2019). [Introducing the stars](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-11704-7). Cham: Springer Nature Switzerland AG.

Comment: Can you credit the original source for the diagram? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the diagram as a whole, the bottom line seems to be the type of object that a star in that category will evolve into.  So a large star that is variable due to mass loss will explode in a type II SN and evolve to either a Black Hole, or a Neutron star (which may become variable as a pulsar but ultimately evolves to a non variable NS.

Looking down the right. We see "mass exchange variables (ie novae) and dwarf novae such as U Gem or Z And will ultimately evolve into one of three types of stellar remnant: Black dwarfs, neutron stars or black holes. Black dwarfs are the final stage of evolution of white dwarfs.

Therefore I surmise that BD means Black Dwarf.